# What actually happens when a method is the condition of an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, methods

```
if (username.value.length >= 8) {

       msg.style.background = "green"
       msg.appendChild(validMsg)

       if (msg.appendChild(invalidMsg)) {
       msg.removeChild(invalidMsg)
       }

   }
```

**msg** references a div

**validMsg** and **invalidMsg** are both text nodes, created via createTextNode

This is being used to add a success message and to remove a warning message on a page, if the warning message is present.

It works without the nested condition, but returns an error ('The node to be removed is not a child of this node')

I have other solutions, but would like to know specifically what happens with the nested **if**. I know an **if** can be used to check for JavaScript features, but in the case above, is it actually executing the appendChild method and then removing the child, or just checking if it *can* appendChild?

A better solution using the approach above would be appreciated also.

Comment: _"It works without the nested condition,"_ - What _"nested condition"_? _"but returns an error ('The node to be removed is not a child of this node')"_ - So it is not working. But that error doesn't match the code in your question. `.removeChild()` is only executed when `.appendChild()` was successful, which makes `invalidMsg` a child of `msg` (https://jsfiddle.net/7r53x1zu/)

Comment: @rbeatt, this particular method returns the child node. So maybe it's truthy?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to message a user if the content of a form input is OK. Here are two examples. On using CSS and the other CSS and JavaScript.

```css
span.invalid, span.valid {
  display: none;
}

input:invalid ~ span.invalid {
  display: inline;
}

input:valid ~ span.valid {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" minlength="8" required/>
    <span class="valid">OK</span>
    <span class="invalid">not OK</span>
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("submit");
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.invalid').classList.add('show');
}, true);

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.invalid').classList.remove('show');
}, false);
```

```css
span.invalid {
  display: none;
}

span.show {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" minlength="8" required/>
    <span class="invalid">not OK</span>
  </label>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Great solutions, and much appreciated. Thanks @chrwahl

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

I tested it again and removed the code between the curly braces, namely:

```
 msg.removeChild(invalidMsg)
```

This results in both the valid and invalid messages appearing on the page, so

```
 if (msg.appendChild(invalidMsg))
```

is adding the invalidMsg. The removeChild method is then taking it away again.

It all works exactly the same if like this:

```
   if (username.value.length >= 8) {

        msg.style.background = "green"
        msg.appendChild(validMsg)

        msg.appendChild(invalidMsg) 
        msg.removeChild(invalidMsg)
    }
```